# Symfony2 + Doctrine + case statements: how to do a case statement in DQL or other?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to use **`case statements`** into my **query builder**...

My query is something like this:

```
        $query = $this->getEntityManager('V')->createQuery(
            'SELECT  V,
                (CASE unit  WHEN "DAY"      THEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL start_date DAY ) 
                            WHEN "MONTH"    THEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL start_date MONTH )
                            WHEN "YEAR"     THEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL start_date YEAR ) 
                 END as startDate
                ) 
            FROM AppMyBundle:Entity V

             WHERE 1=1 
             ORDER BY date ASC'
        );
```

Note that it is correct in MySQL.

I don't know how to solve it...

If you have another idea, feel free to help me :)

Any idea?

Comment: you should probably use a NativeQuery and ResultSetMapping http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/native-sql.html

Comment: Thanks I have found another solution use a real mysql query using the container service. I try your solution and I'll give a feedback...

Answer (score 0):

```
$query =  $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare(
        "SELECT  V.id,
            (CASE WHEN "DAY"      THEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL start_date DAY ) 
                  WHEN "MONTH"    THEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL start_date MONTH )
                  WHEN "YEAR"     THEN DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL start_date YEAR ) 
             END as startDate
            ) 
        FROM table_name V

         WHERE V.id = :id 
         ORDER BY date ASC"
    );
 $query->bindValue('id', $id);
 $query->execute();   
 $results = $query->fetchAll();
```

Try this one I hope it working for you
Thanks,
Ashok Chitroda