# How to use "case when" in query

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

I have this query:

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u,COUNT(u) AS nb_renouvellement,
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.`Criticity` = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  nb_majeur,
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.`Criticity` = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  nb_critique
    FROM AdminBlogBundle:AlertesBss2  f
GROUP BY f.BSC");
$listes = $query->getResult();
```

but I have this error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 45: Error: Expected Literal, got 'CASE'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 + Doctrine + case statements: how to do a case statement in DQL or other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974007/symfony2-doctrine-case-statements-how-to-do-a-case-statement-in-dql-or-othe)

Comment: what is "u", its in SELECT but not in GROUP BY

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9795412/1218997) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Criticity should not be in quotes, and it should be group by f.u